# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement Getting this error when trying to call google place search api

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Getting `'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'` error when I am trying run this ajax code to fetch all ATM within 1 km range.

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json";
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        'location': '-33.8670522,151.1957362',
        'radius': 1000,
        'types': 'atm',
        'name': '',
        'sensor': false,
        'key': API_KEY
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

I have searched for many articles but didnt found the solution. If I remove `'p'` from `'jsonp'` there is no response cause it is Cross Domain. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: missing a semicolon in  `alert('success')` Are you using strict mode..?

Comment: added semicolon, same err. strict mode ?

Comment: What line is that error pointing at?

Comment: It is not showing any line. When i inspect using firebug i see that i am getting response but cannot move further since getting this err.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example? jsfiddle?

Comment: I want to fetch all atm, hospitals, restaurants within 1 km range from a particular place(addr/latlng). For this i am using google place search api. Sending example link like below (given on google site).
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Comment: I am doing this by sending Ajax request to this url, but facing this err. while receiving the response.

Comment: what is jsfiddle? i am not using it. please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax-error in the code, the error comes via the response.

The places-webservice doesn't support JSONP, you can't request this service via `$.ajax`

Use the methods of the places-library of the Maps-Javascript-API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: Thanks Molle for the reference. Can you tell me how can i remove or suppress 'html_attributions' from response?
    {
  "html_attributions" : [
    "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
  ],

Comment: Basically the response is an object, and html_attributions is a property of this object, properties of an object may be removed via [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). I will not give  further advice, because the html_attributions must always be present when you use the resullts, see: https://developers.google.com/places/policies#attribution_requirements